# Android + Firebase: retrieve multiple values and get the sum

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino

[image: Sample Firebase Data]

Hello, I am new to Android development, so I'm hoping for your understanding. I would like to ask how I can retrieve all data under 'values' and get the sum. As you can see, the 'keys' are random-generated keys, which were sent from an Arduino device to Firebase, but the values being sent to Firebase are correct. I want to get the sum and display it on an Android app in a single TextView. I am using Android Studio as IDE for my Android app.

I've tried other snippets from Stack Overflow as well, but it's too confusing for my level of knowledge in Android and I can't make it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this, may be this will help to achieve your task.

```
  DatabaseReference  ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  ref.child("data/values").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  int toalSum=0;
                  if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //depending upon what datatype youre using caste to it.
                        totalSum = totalSum+(int)snapshot.getValue();
                    }
                    Log.d("LOG","Toatal sum-"+totalSum)
                  }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()` will return size

```
    DatabaseReference  dbref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    dbref.child("url/values")
          .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    int size = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(); //Here u can see the count
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

To count those values, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference valuesRef = rootRef.child("data").child("values");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int sum = o;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int value = ds.getValue(Integer.class);
            sum = sum + value;

        }
        Log.d("TAG", sum);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
valuesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your outout will be:

```
1780
```

Answer (score 0):

try this basic split string.

```
database.geteDatabase().getReference().child("data").child("values")
   .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          //dataSnapshot.getValue().toString() = {a=1,b=2,c=3}
          String[] value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().split("[{,}]");

          String[] getA= value[1].split("=");  //value[1]='a=1'
          String[] getB= value[2].split("=");  //value[2]='b=2'
          String[] getC= value[3].split("=");  //value[3]='c=3'

          //what you want to do here.
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
     });
```

**this can use for other get basic multi value from firebase database.**